# HQL :Hibernate update query

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, struts2, hql

i use struts2 and hibernate jpa for my app and i have an error when traying using update query with hibernate
 here is my code :

in my class dao

```
@Override
public void UpdateNoteEvaluation() {
    try {
        String hql="update Evaluation e " +
                "SET e.Eval_NoteGlobal =: ( SELECT SUM( sv.SousEval_Note ) AS sum FROM sousevaluation sv )" +
                "ORDER BY EVAL_ID DESC LIMIT 1 ";
        Query q= session.createQuery(hql);

        q.executeUpdate();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        transaction.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

in my class Action :

```
public String saveOrUpdate(){   
    sousevaldao.UpdateNoteEvaluation();
    System.out.println("update note ok ok");

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

so here  i can't make the update  i get this error :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: node to traverse cannot be null!
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.util.NodeTraverser.traverseDepthFirst(NodeTraverser.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:277)
```

knowing i have test the  update query im phpmyadmin  it's work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If query has been tested to be working one via phpMyAdmin, it is quite clear that query is SQL query - not a HQL query. Also syntax of query seems to contain MySQL SQL dialect specific  `LIMIT` clause.

`Query` for native SQL queries can be created via `Session.createSQLQuery(String queryString)` method:

```
String sql = ...
Query q = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
```

Comment: +1 this `Query q = session.createSQLQuery(sql);` work finely but i want if You can adjusted with syntax of hql